# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' help?

Tags: php, parse-error

I'm trying to make a photo gallery plugin for express engine, yet it's giving me this error and everything seems to close. Any help?

```
$whats_gonna_happen=$_GET['pictures'];

class upload_pictures
{
    public function upload_pictures
    {
        if (!isset($whats_gonna_happen))
        {
            $uploads='';
            $cout=1;
            $stuff=$this->EE->db->query('SELECT id, name FROM albums');
            $albums_list='';
            while ($row=$stuff->result_array())
            {
                $albums_list .= "<option value=" . $row[0] . ">" . $row[1] . "</option>\n";
            }  
            mysql_free_result($stuff);
            echo '
            <html>
                <head><title>Pictures upload</title></head>
                <body>
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_page.php?pictures=1" method="POST" name="stough">
                        <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" style="width: 90%">
                            <tr><td>
                                Choose album : 
                                <select name="albums">
                                ' . $albums_list . '
                                </select>
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr><td>
                                <br /> photo : <br />
                                <input type="file" name="filename"  />
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr><td>
                                Caption : <br />
                                <textarea name="captions" cols="60" rows="1"></textarea>
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr><td>
                            <input type="submit" name="captions" value="Upload" />
                            </td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>
            ';
        }
```

Comment: Next time, please post a more focused snippet or tell us on that line the error occurred.

Comment: you're missing function and class closing brackets...

Comment: Side note: `if (!isset($whats_gonna_happen))` will always be true

Comment: fyi, `mysql_free_result` is usually not necessary
`

Comment: class name and function name are same..it means its a constructor..and better to use constructor like __construct() and also on function declaration missing ().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
public function upload_pictures
```

should be:

```
public function upload_pictures()
```

Comment: @user677756: The little things are often the easiest to overlook. Let us know if we can help in the future.

Answer (score 3):

forgot the () in your function declaration

```
public function upload_pictures()
```

your also missing 2 closing brackets in the snippet